# How do I select one row from a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

If I know the query only returns one row, and more specefically, in this case one value,

```
$full_name = database::query("SELECT concat (fname, ' ', lname) from cr WHERE email='$email'");
```

how do I get that value into a single variable.  Database::query returns the value form mysql_query.  The query above insert "Resource ID 4" in to mysql table.

[image: Credentials(cr)]

[image: Tweets(tw)]

Comment: Take a look at mysql_fetch_row()

Comment: What class is that you're using? You should almost certainly be using PDO to access a database - http://www.php.net/pdo

Comment: @nick rulez - don't point Chris in the direction of less safe methods

Comment: @adam. Sorry, I don't know that class.

Comment: Sorry @nick, I didn't mean to be so harsh. PDO works on prepared statements, so protects the server from SQL injection attacks

Comment: As an (important) aside, the code as written is very vulneralbe to SQL Injection.  If you're not familiar with that topic, suggest you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786034/can-parameterized-statement-stop-all-sql-injection

Comment: @adam. You're right but I hope he does some kind of input validation before pass it to the query.

Comment: this is just a prototype I'm trying to get up and running, I'll add security from there. msyql_real_escape_string() is built in to my post class though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about `database::query()`, but [`mysql_query()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_query) does indeed return a resource.

Once you have that resource, you must fetch your data from it, using, for example, [**`mysql_fetch_array()`**](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) :

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array($full_name);
```

Note that there are several `mysql_fetch_*` function, depending on what kind of result your want *(array, object, ...)* :

- [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)
- [`mysql_fetch_object()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)
- [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: An array, an object, and an associative array, what about a single value, i.e. the simplest case?  I keep seeing the array example and I know I could use it but I keep thinking there is one just for a single value?

Comment: @Chris In any case, you must fetch the row *(and a row generally contains several values -- one being the exception)* ; then, you can access each data *(one, in your case)* that's in that row ;;; if you want to see what's in `$data`, you can use `var_dump($data);` to get a dump of that variable's content.

Comment: So all "grabs" from the table are row based?

Comment: Yep :-) *(actually, even if your select only returns one line of one column, that's still sent as... well, a row)*

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT concat (fname, ' ', lname) from cr WHERE email='$email'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
echo $row[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what else your database class has to offer, but using built in php mysql function you could use:

```
$full_name = database::query("SELECT concat (fname, ' ', lname)
     from cr WHERE email='$email'");
$full_name = mysql_fetch_row($full_name);
$full_name = $full_name[0];
```