# Stored procedure to find next and previous row in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic

Right now I have this code to find next and previous rows using SQL Server 2005. `intID` is the gallery id number using bigint data type:

```
SQL = "SELECT TOP 1 max(p.galleryID) as previousrec, min(n.galleryID) AS nextrec FROM gallery AS p CROSS JOIN gallery AS n where p.galleryid < '"&intID&"' and n.galleryid > '"&intID&"'"
Set rsRec = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsRec.Open sql, Conn
strNext = rsRec("nextrec")
strPrevious = rsRec("previousrec")
rsRec.close
set rsRec = nothing
```

Problem Number 1:

The newest row will return nulls on the 'next record' because there is none. The oldest row will return nulls because there isn't a 'previous record'. So if either the 'next record' or 'previous record' doesn't exist then it returns nulls for both.

Problem Number 2:

I want to create a stored procedure to call from the DB so intid can just be passed to it

TIA

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), anyone?

Comment: @Oded, nah. That's a [myth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786034/can-parameterized-statement-stop-all-sql-injection]).

Comment: @Ben - what is a myth? The SQL Injection is a very possible with this code?

Comment: @Oded I know; and with Hogan's answer below. The link goes to a question on why it get's missed so often.

Comment: We already have an included file to prevent SQL injection. The important thing here right now is to solve the problem, then i'll use ADODB command with parameters...then create the stored procedure. I see more comments about sql injection rather than an answer to the question

Comment: That's why those are comments and not answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will yield `NULL` for previous on the first row, and `NULL` for next on the last row. Though your ordering seems backwards to me; why is "next" lower than "previous"?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetGalleryBookends
    @GalleryID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ;WITH n AS 
    (
        SELECT galleryID, rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
          OVER (ORDER BY galleryID) 
          FROM dbo.gallery
    )
    SELECT
      previousrec = MAX(nA.galleryID), 
      nextrec     = MIN(nB.galleryID)
    FROM n 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN n AS nA
    ON nA.rn = n.rn - 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN n AS nB
    ON nB.rn = n.rn + 1
    WHERE n.galleryID = @galleryID;
END
GO
```

Also, it doesn't make sense to want an empty string instead of `NULL`. Your ASP code can deal with `NULL` values just fine, otherwise you'd have to convert the resulting integers to strings every time. If you really want this you can say:

```
      previousrec = COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), MIN(nA.galleryID)), ''), 
      nextrec     = COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), MAX(nB.galleryID)), '')
```

But this will no longer work well when you move from ASP to ASP.NET because types are much more explicit. Much better to just have the application code be able to deal with, instead of being afraid of, `NULL` values.

This seems like a lot of work to get the previous and next ID, without retrieving any information about the current ID. Are you implementing paging? If so I highly recommend reviewing [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/) and [this follow-up conversation](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic672980-329-1.aspx).

Comment: i can understand the next value to be null on the newest record because there isnt a next record, but the prvious is being returned as null also on the first record

Comment: What value do you want returned for the row previous to the first row? What row comes before the first row? Word problems and guessing aren't fun; ***please*** show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (nb not tested)

```
SELECT TOP 1 max(p.galleryID) as previousrec, min(n.galleryID) AS nextrec 
       FROM gallery AS p 
       CROSS JOIN gallery AS n 
              where (p.galleryid < @intID or p.galleryid is null)
              and (n.galleryid > @intID  or n.galleryid is null)
```

I'm assuming you validate that `intID` is an integer before using this code.

As for a stored procedure -- are you asking how to write a stored procedure?  If so there are many tutorials which are quite good on the web.

Comment: same affect with your code the first and last record returns NULL so no ID is given if one isnt found

Comment: @Patriotec: so what do you want to receive in that case? Same result for both, next and previous records?

Comment: If one doesn't EXIST set that value to "" and return the other. If both EXIST return both next and previous records. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can get that result with `MAX(ISNULL(p.galleryID),"")`

Comment: Same result. Something wrong with the query in the stored  procedure. Also you can't assign "" in SQL if ISNULL. It's not allow. Even if I try to do MAX(ISNULL(p.galleryID),"norec") or MAX(ISNULL(p.galleryID),0). Nothing seems to work

Comment: Sorry @Patriotec -- a string constant uses `''` not double quotes.  What is the error you get -- please update the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Since Hogan contributed with the SQL statement, let me contribute with the stored proc part:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetNextAndPreviousRecords 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @intID int 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1 max(p.galleryID) as previousrec, min(n.galleryID) AS nextrec 
       FROM gallery AS p 
       CROSS JOIN gallery AS n 
              where (p.galleryid < @intID or p.galleryid is null)
              and (n.galleryid > @intID  or n.galleryid is null)

END
```

And you call this from code as follows (assuming VB.NET):

```
 Using c As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
       c.Open()
       Dim command = New SqlCommand("spGetNextAndPreviousRecords")

       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intID", yourID)
       Dim reader as SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
       While(reader.Read())
          ' read the result here
       End While
End Using
```

Comment: Actually its a classic ASP application using VBScript. Thanks !!

Comment: @Patriotec: well, at least the stored proc part will help you.

Comment: Thanks again for contributing the method for stored procedures. Now I use it all the time. It's just faster.