# How to seperate the ''select top * x" from query string?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, t-sql

I am trying to sent a query string to the database, but got this error -->

> A TOP can not be used in the same query or sub-query as a OFFSET.

When I debugged the query string , I observe that
`"select * from TABLE"` is changed to `"select * from TABLE Fetch Next 50 Rows Only"`(where number of columns =50(already set)).

**Required Output**

```
select top * x from [TABLE]
```

to

```
select * from [TABLE] Fetch Next x Rows Only
```

**What I tried**

I tried to use , find and replace the 'top * x' to integer x and *

```
 string CommandText = "select * from TABLE";
 CommandText =CommandText
 + orderby + " OFFSET " + (request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize
 + " ROWS FETCH NEXT " + request.PageSize + " ROWS ONLY";
```

Kindly help me to find the solution.

Comment: I am unclear as to what you are trying to do. Firstly, building a SQL Query in this way is dangers and could result in SQL injection. Secondly, the FETCH keyword I believe only works with cursors so it wouldn't work in this scenario. Please clarify what it is you are trying to accomplish and I may be able to help.

Comment: Why are you trying to add a `TOP` over a SQL statement that already retrieves the amount of rows you want?

Comment: @Cleptus since the number data required for grid is fixed in the range 10,20,30,40 etc instead of it i need user defined range.

Comment: It is redundant, you already achieve it with the `FETCH NEXT x ROWS ONLY`, check my answer

Comment: @BrandonJohnson In SQL Server it is valid using FETCH in an SELECT statement

Comment: You should **absolutely never** run arbitrary SQL from external sources. Never. That is a security hole that you could drive a truck through.

Comment: Thanks @Cleptus I just have never seen it done. This is why I'm not a DBA lol.

Comment: @DanielMann changed my answer to have more enphasis on why OP should use parametrized queries

Comment: @Cleptus A parameterized query won't solve the problem. If this page in question is user-facing, a savvy user will notice the SQL and realize they can write any SQL they want. And then you have a security hole.

Comment: @DanielMann No, the database engine does use the value received as is, with no interpreting it any further. Check [Can parameterized statement stop all SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786034/can-parameterized-statement-stop-all-sql-injection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to avoid string concatenation to make the SQL statement you could (and IMHO you **should**) use a parametrized query. It is a security risk called SQL Injection you should always avoid. For example:

```cs
string commandText = @"
SELECT * FROM dbo.TABLE
ORDER BY orderColum
OFFSET @offset ROWS
FETCH NEXT @page ROWS ONLY";

command.CommandText = commandText;
command.Parameters.Add(SqlDbType.Int, "@offset").Value =  (request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize;
command.Parameters.Add(SqlDbType.Int, "@page").Value =  request.PageSize;
```

Please do note that parametrized queries do have a bonus, the database engine will likely do an execution plan for it and future queries using the same `CommandText` would execute faster because of that plan regarless of having different values in their parameters.