# How to SQL inject parameterized queries

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I read online that SQL injection is possible through parameterized queries but I didn't find anything about how to do it. Does someone know how it's possible to SQL inject parameterized queries?

For parameterized queries I mean this:

`'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [user, password], ...`

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Please include the source of that hearsay.

Comment: Uwe Keim, the impaler, i read it in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786034/can-parameterized-statement-stop-all-sql-injection

Comment: JoelCrypto yes, thank you

Comment: I wrote one of the answers that said there are edge cases of dynamic SQL where parameters cannot be used, therefore parameters can't solve _all_ SQL injection vulnerabilities. Nevertheless, parameters are effective and the best option for many cases. For the cases where parameters cannot be used, such as identifiers and expressions and keywords, a common solution is to use allow-listing.

Comment: SQL Injection occurs when a somewhat careless or naive developer implements Dynamic SQL. Dynamic SQL essentially a technique where you concatenate strings to produce SQL statements. Now, prepared statements prevent this to happen for most use cases, **but not all of them**. For example, DB2 does not accept parameters for the LIMIT-equivalent clause; or you need to query a table which name is known at runtime only. You need to use Dynamic SQL for those cases; sanitize input carefully. Also, you may need to use a badly crafted stored procedure that assembles queries on the fly. Beware.